# How to avoid zooming on background image?

Tags: css, html

We can scale background image by using meta tag view port. I have background image and I can zoom in/out that image very well BUT I have some more stuffs on background image(text and Button), when I zoomed background image then button and text are also getting zoom BUT I don't want to zoom them with view port scale.
Is this possible to avoid zoom for some specific elements by using view port scaling?
Here is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=0.5, maximum scale=1.5,
minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device height,
target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

 <style>
 #maincontent {
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 50;
 }

 #score {
margin: 0 0 0 0;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: 50;
position: fixed;
 }

 #scoreCount {

font-size: 100%;
 }
#countdown{
font-size: 100%;

  }
 #reset{
margin: 0 0 0 0;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: 50;
position: fixed;

 } 


  </style>

  </head>
  <body>

<img alt="Loading" id="background" />
<div id="maincontent">
<div id="score">
        <p id="scoreCount">
            <b></b>
        </p>
        <p id="countdown">Time Limit</p>
    </div>
    <div id="reset">
    <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>

</div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

I have tried by giving position:fixed and background-attachment:fixed BUT not working.Please anybody help to get solve this. I am stuck with this last two days. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Gal V and I have also searched more on this topic. "Is this possible to avoid zoom for some specific elements by using view port scaling?". According to my research we can't(I am not sure 100%) avoid some specific elements to zoom by using meta tag view port scaling. Don't know correct answer. If any body know answer it.

Answer (score 0):

change your `viewport` tag to this one:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

your code has differences between initial scale to maximum scale, and the zoom is available because of that. notice that in my suggestion all the values are the same.

hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer. if v change all to 1 Then how can I zoom??

Comment: Actually I need to zoom in/out only background image by using view port other all(text(<p> tag) and buttons) should not zoom with view port zoom. How can I avoid zoom for other elements??

Comment: avoid zoom to all elements with my suggested viewport. enable zoom for specific elements by listening to the right events on them. that's the general idea

Comment: Yes u r right BUT I need to add zoom in/out for a specific elements by using view port scaling only. Is this possible to avoid zoom for some specific elements?

Comment: Oh kya???.. I was getting some problems for zooming background image in HTML5 canvas so I used this BUT at last again problem.